# Return next value in array if Condition is true

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, loops

I have an array of DateTimes:

```
public DateTime GetNextGame()
{
    DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[]
    {
        new DateTime(2016, 4, 11, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 4, 12, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 4, 13, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 5, 30, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 5, 31, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 6, 1, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 6, 2, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 6, 14, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 6, 15, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 6, 16, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 8, 16, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 8, 17, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 12, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 13, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 14, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 19, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 20, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 21, 7, 5, 0),
        new DateTime(2016, 9, 22, 7, 5, 0)
    };
```

My question is.. how I do return the next value in the array if the current value doesn't meet the condition?  I did some research on this and found a similar question but it was in PHP which I didn't understand.

so I have a loop going through the array then the conditional statement:

```
foreach(DateTime date in dateTimes)
{
    if(date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return //next value in array?
    }
}
```

also trying to return the date `.ToShortDateString` along with the `.ToShortTimeString` for my view.

I want it to look like this.. "The Next Game is Monday, March 3rd at 7:05 PM"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `for` instead of `foreach`. `for(int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Length; i++) { date = dateTimes[i] ... }`

Comment: you can keep `counter` to get next value, but why you are not using `for`?

Comment: For this kind of problem, it's probably just easier to use a normal for loop and manually index into the array.  Then just use `index + 1` (and do the proper exception handling).

Comment: How do you know that the next value will meet the condition? Do you really want to return that anyway? Perhaps you should be using `return dateTimes.First(...)`

Comment: Yeah, I'd use a normal for loop, if you wish to ensure that you move forward in the correct order. And simply write a method that does that check for you, based on each entry in the array.

Comment: @SeM I know about the for loop and that this would most likely be a good scenario to use it, and honestly I don't know why I didn't use it.. haha just a dumb decision..

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid ok, anyway, I've added answer for `foreach` loop.

Comment: Have you noticed that this condition is pointless? `DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay` is midnight and no other time will be before it. So it's false for every `DateTime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so dateTimes[i].Date < DateTime.Today.Date would work?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: You don't `DateTime.Today.Date`, if you use `DateTime.Today` you get a `DateTime` of today's midnight, so the `Date` is redundant because it's returning the same. This is sufficient: `if(dateTimes[i].Date < DateTime.Today)...`

Comment: @TimSchmelter got it, I saw that it return a Date when I hovered over it, but I just wanted to make sure, so I can see the redundancy.. one question.. can you explain the DateTimes.Length - 1?  so I don't want the counter going past the second to last index in the array?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36132990/284240) to include it. The reason for  the `dateTimes.Length - 1` in my for-loop was that you want the next DateTime in the array. If you are checking the last item in an array there is no "next" item and you would get an exception at `return dateTimes[i + 1];`. That's why my for-loop stops at the second last `DateTime`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter okay got it. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `for`-loop if you need to access the next(or previous) item:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Length - 1; i++)
{
    (dateTimes[i].TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return dateTimes[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Apart from that, your comparison is pointless:

```
if(date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
{
    // this will never be true
}
```

`DateTime.TimeOfDay` returns the `TimeSpan` of a `DateTime`, so the time component. `DateTime.Today` returns today's midnight so it's `TimeOfDay` will be  `TimeSpan.Zero`. That's why `date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay` will never be true.

I assume that you want the first `DateTime` which date is before today. Then use this:

```
if(date.Date < DateTime.Today)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The Linq `SkipWhile` operator could be used:

```
            DateTime firstValid = dateTimes.SkipWhile(d => d.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay).First();
```

EDIT: Just wanted to mention that we assume the array is already ordered ascending.

Comment: or add an `OrderBy` clause.

Comment: Well, I didn't know whether the data could be modified, so I made it clear that we provided answers based on the original data.

Comment: well, sure, I understand why you added it :) But if the data *is* unordered, one could add an `OrderBy` in order to sort it. I figured it would be pretty much the equal amount of text and it would provide more information instead of just disclaiming the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for-loop instead foreach.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Length; i++)
{
    if(dateTimes[i].TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay && i < dateTimes.Length - 1)
    {
        return dateTimes[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Also note you´ll need the check that you´re not out of the bounds of the array by writing `if(i < dateTimes.Length)`.

You can also combine the loop-conditions a bit:

```
for(int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if(dateTimes[i].TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return dateTimes[i + 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can put this restriction `i < dateTimes.Length` in `for` statement

Answer (score 1):

You could do simply

```
return dateTimes.OrderBy(dateTime => dateTime).FirstOrDefault(dateTime => dateTime > DateTime.Now);
```

Or if you want to use `Today` and `TimeOfDay`

```
return dateTimes.OrderBy(dateTime => dateTime).FirstOrDefault(dateTime => dateTime.Date > DateTime.Today &&  dateTime.TimeOfDay > DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay);
```

Comment: Short working answer. But OP did not want `DateTime.Now` but `DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I added an alternative version

Answer (score 1):

Try `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dateTimes.Length; ++i) {
  DateTime date = dateTimes[i];

  if (date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay) {
    if (i < dateTimes.Length - 1) // not the last item
      return date[i + 1];
    else {
      //TODO: there's no "next item" for the last one
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you, for some reasons, don't want to use `for` loop, then try this:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(DateTime date in dateTimes)
{
    if(date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return dateTimes[counter + 1];
    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: this is just an obfuscated `for` loop - you have the initializer, the condition and the iterator. How is this not a for loop? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
foreach(DateTime date in dateTimes)
{
    if(!(date.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay))
    {
        continue;
    }
    return date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you know in advance your array is completely sorted, use:

```
var idx = Array.BinarySearch(dateTimes, DateTime.Now);

return dateTimes[idx >= 0 ? idx : ~idx];
```

Like many other solutions here, this will fail badly if there is no upcoming "next game". Check that you are within the range of the array if that should be handled more gracefully.